# Indeterminate ProgressBar with animation and rounded corners

Tags: android, android-view

How can an indeterminate progressbar be created that is animated, and has rounded corners?
For some reason if you use your own animation-list as animation, the shape can't be defined. It will always be sharp, edgy, not rounded.

This is what I need:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I've followed the coding approach. Basically generating a tiled, and clipped drawable for each frame. I believe the original progressbar does something similar.

(some parts are omitted for brevity)

```
final ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(6 /*px*/, null, null));
final AnimationDrawable background = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_bar_indeterminate_animation_list);
final int N = background.getNumberOfFrames();
AnimationDrawable newBg = new AnimationDrawable();
newBg.setOneShot(background.isOneShot());

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    final Bitmap tileBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) background.getFrame(i)).getBitmap();

    final BitmapShader bitmapShader = new BitmapShader(tileBitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    shape.getPaint().setShader(bitmapShader);

    final Drawable result = new ClipDrawable(shape, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
    result.setLevel(10000);
    newBg.addFrame(result, background.getDuration(i));
}
newBg.setLevel(10000);
progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(newBg);
```

`progress_bar_indeterminate_animation_list` is:

```
<animation-list android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/install_progressbar_indeterminate1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/install_progressbar_indeterminate2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/install_progressbar_indeterminate3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

The whole code is here: http://mikinw.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/indeterminate-progressbar-with-rounded.html

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to set indeterminate drawable with the code.

```
// ProgressBar when parsing indeterminate drawable from XML sets rounded corners.   progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar));
```

then use the progressbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_2b" android:duration="100" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_1b" android:duration="100" />
</animation-list>
```

As you can see from the `android:drawable` above, there are 2 images. progress_1b and progress_2b.

They would look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/progress_1"
    android:tileMode="repeat" >
</bitmap>`
```

Works for moi.

Comment: I can't currently see how whould this have rounded corner. Or if the drawable has rounded corner, than how would it be tiled in a nice way.